# appcelerator - start activity from service

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I try to start activity from service :

```
var launcherIntent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        className : 'net.iamyellow.gcmjs.GcmjsActivity',
        packageName : Ti.App.id,
        flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
});
launcherIntent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(launcherIntent);
```

this work when app in background, but does not work when app is killed, because currentActivity is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a valid bug. Appcelerator team is currently working on this. So we can hope it will be fixed soon. You can follow that in the following link.
[Link](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20490)